Generate report in Playwright
I am trying to do a test using Playwright. I understand that when I run the test, a HTML report should be automatically generated and saved in the playwright-report folder, and a XML report should be created in the playwright-tests folder. The HTML works okay, but the XML is not being created and the folder is empty.
This is the structure that I have:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
And this is the playwright.configuration.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('@playwright/test');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './e2e/src/tests',
  outputDir: 'playwright-tests',
  webServer: {
    command: 'ng serve -c production',
    port: 4200,
    timeout: 120 * 1000,
    reuseExistingServer: true,
  },
  workers: 4,
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://xxx/',
    storageState: 'e2e/.auth/storageState.json',
    browserName: 'chromium',
    headless: true,
    viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: 'on',
  },
  reporter: [
    ['list'],
    ['html', { outputFolder: '/playwright-report', open: 'never' }],
    ['junit', { outputFile: 'newresults.xml' }]
  ]
});

I am working in WSL, and I already gave permission to the folders to write on them.

What can I do to fix this and get the XML report?

Thanks!


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/51ysy6jH.png

